# How to get Duration time of a tasks in celery?

Tags: celery

I want to measure a task runtime in celery.

I know we can use time for start time and end time.
and then get duration.
but I want to use built-in celery.

for example in this URL we have task events:
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#task-succeeded

but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tiny example of using the [Celery monitoring](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html) API. It subscribes to be notified of almost all Celery events: https://gitlab.com/dejan/ceex/-/blob/main/exe/celemon.py . As you can see, it just prints out some useful details about tasks. At work I have a much more complex monitor that stores all events in a database so that we can easily do analytics and various reports...